# IIS Http to Https when web app is within the site

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

I have this rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" negate="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
</rules>
    </rewrite>
```

And I want to rediret all http to https trafic, but the thing is my web app is not in the root folder, so it's like this:

`http:\\my-site.com\MyWebApp\some-parameters-here`

and after redirection it goes to:

`https:\\my-site.com\some-parameters-here`

...instead of

`https:\\my-site.com\MyWebApp\some-parameters-here`

How this redirection can be fixed without hard-codding that part in URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works for me:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"  trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^((.+)?my-site\.com)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

The key is that replacement: `{R:1}`. This is allowed to keep full link without `HTTP_HOST`

**UPDATE**
About your comment

You can use:

```
   <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
      redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>
```

Comment: Sure. You can remove that line. This part of our config. We have couple sites without a certificate.